# Sending gmail emails through python + smtplib. Can't separate body from subject

Tags: python, character-encoding, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I want to send emails from my gmail acocunt through a python script.
And my code works.

The only thing is I want the emails to have a subject and a body.
But my script is putting everything in the subject.

Here's my code:

```
import smtplib

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()

    smtp.login("MY EMAIL", "MY PASSWORD")

    subject = "Contract Details"
    body = "Grettings. Here are the contract details. Thank you."

    msg = f"""Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"""
    email = "MY EMAIL"
    def encode(x):
        """ The replaces in this function fix some problems in the encoding.
            For now, they are not that relevant. They work. """
        return str(x.encode("ascii", errors="ignore")).replace("b'", "").replace("'", "")

    #  I'm sending it to myself, so the first two arguments are the same:
    smtp.sendmail(encode(email), encode(email), encode(msg))
```

I've tried to figure out the solution online, and a lot of videos and articles say that you should use two newlines to separate the subject from the body.
That's why I'm using `msg = f"""Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"""`

However, I get this:
[image]

As you can see both my subject and body are in the subject (red), and the body is blank.

I've also tried no breaklines, one breakline, three breaklines.
I even tried to write `msg = f"""Subject: {subject}\n\nBody: {body}"""`
But nothing works...

How do I separate the body from the subject?

Comment: @snakecharmerb tried it now, doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I changed:

```
smtp.sendmail(encode(email), encode(email), encode(msg))
```

To:

```
smtp.sendmail(encode(email), encode(email), msg)
```

And now it works.